# ESXi very slow with WD reds

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp, performance-tuning

I have a small company and we offer tech support to small companies. I've been using the HP Gen8 MicroServer in most of them as a replacement of homebuilt computers for some time.

Sometimes customers have more than one application, and in such cases we've been using the free ESXi hipervisor to virtualize two or more VMs in the microserver. It's not really a fast server but it's fast enough for most applications (most of them need a windows VM to server an ancient accounting software, and a pfSense instance)

I have 11 of these deployed, and last month I was asked for a new one for a branch office.

I configured the server exactly as I've always done, 16GB DDR3, RAID1, and in all cases but this one it's the G2020T variant. This one is newer and it has a Xeon E3-1220L, slightly more powerful.

Anyway, this last one has 2x 2TB WD reds, I've used WD blacks and WD greens before with no issues so I thought red would be a good compromise but the end result turned out very very slow. I'm pretty sure it's an I/O issue since non-io related tasks are fine.

I tried a very basic benchmark, with dd I wrote a 1GB file to the datastore on two servers:

Older one:

```
time dd if=/dev/zero of=file bs=1000000 count=1000
1000+0 records in
1000+0 records out
real    1m 6.89s
user    0m 1.00s
sys     0m 0.00s
```

New one

```
time dd if=/dev/zero of=file bs=1000000 count=1000
1000+0 records in
1000+0 records out
real    2m 23.58s
user    0m 0.55s
sys     0m 0.00s
```

The service console is quite resource limited so I thought I should test a VM.
Both VMs are identical, results:

```
time dd if=/dev/zero of=file bs=1000000 count=1000
1000+0 records in
1000+0 records out
1000000000 bytes (1.0 GB) copied, 9.96486 s, 100 MB/s

real    0m10.232s
user    0m0.010s
sys     0m6.924s
```

New one:

```
time dd if=/dev/zero of=file bs=1000000 count=1000
1000+0 records in
1000+0 records out
1000000000 bytes (1.0 GB) copied, 14.8556 s, 67.3 MB/s

real    0m15.305s
user    0m0.018s
sys     0m5.972s
```

Slower but not by a huge margin. VMs feel a lot slower though, are there any other metrics I can use to determine the problem location?

Comment: WD Reds are intended for bulk storage, not speed, so this sort of performance really isn't out of line.

Comment: Did you mean to say raid1?  Check the partition tables both on the real drives and in the vm and make sure they are 4k aligned.

Comment: yeah I mean raid1, my bad, partitions are aligned.
I'm moving to thick provisioned VMs to see if it makes a real difference

Comment: You should use RE or Blue. Black is more suited for high power workstations, Red for archiving. Never use Green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I got a notification about this question being still popular.
So here is the actual problem.

In one of the updates, HP shipped a "bad" driver for the custom ESXi ISO, and you had to swap it out for an older version. I solved that back then and never posted here.

Info:

https://woshub.com/esxi-slow-disk-performance-hpe-gen8/

Answer (score 6):

What's the question here?

You don't seem to be comparing apples-to-apples. So I'm not sure if you just want this system to run like your other systems, or if you really care about the cause of the performance difference.

- You could obtain another of the server model and SKU that you're familiar with.
- You could use the same type of disks you used in previous installations.
- You should run firmware updates and ensure that your server's components take advantage of any bugfixes or performance enhancements available to them.

In general, I don't find these Microservers suitable for production use; especially with VMware. The model you've described doesn't have any read or write cache on its RAID controller. Since VM activity is usually a mixture of random read/write activity, your configuration probably won't perform well with two disks.

Also, let's examine your drives:

Western Digital has a few variants of consumer-level SATA drive:

- **Greens** are eco-oriented and minimize power consumption
- **Blues** are standard drives
- **Reds** are variable rotation speed disks
- **Blacks** are premium within the range

Try to use the best drive for your anticipated workload.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.
The question was if there are any other metrics I could use to determine if the problem is definitely I/O

Comment: @AndresSM Yes, I'd check firmware first or swap disks to a known-good model.

Comment: For now moving to thick provisioning seems to have made the solution acceptable. RAID firmware is up to date, anyway my problem is solved but I'm marking your answer as valid since you made several good points.